# i18n language translation in Alloy Titanium

Tags: localization, internationalization, titanium

I have put i18n folder in app/assets/i18n/en/strings.xml as per guide and also I have declared the code in .tss and also in views.xml file in this way

i18n consists of

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="username">Username_Ar</string>
<string name="password">Password</string>
<string name="login">Login</string>
<string name="members_list">Members List</string>
<string name="organizations_list">Organizations List</string>
<string name="membership_number">Membership Number</string>
<string name="real_estate">real_estate</string>
</resources>
```

and view.xml

```
<TextField id="username_textField" hintText="L('username')" borderColor="Gray" borderStyle="Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED" color="#336699" top="170" left="40" width="250" height="40"/>
```

And also I have tried to put the code in .tss file

```
“#password_label”:{
font:

{ fontSize:12 }
,
top: 300,
left: 100,
height: 30,
text:L(“password”)
}
```

But there is no success instead, the mobile view is removing that particular text as i have displayed in the image. (3 brown dots must have ‘username’,’password’ and password) but its empty.

Check this screenshots

https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/51472/3.png
https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/attachment/51473/4.PNG

issue already raised:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-4754

Answer (score 1):

This is really gonna kidding me!

I just fixed the issue by Cleaning up the project. This Titanium is going to eat my brain lol!